# File pond doesn't interact with the server after first upload, not giving server id?

Tags: file, filepond

I do anything to use forcerevert instant file upload etc. Still server id is empty

```
onremovefile(error, file)   File has been removed.
```

Tried the code above to. Why don't just users remove what they just uploaded. Not user-friendly

Comment: Your server should return the `serverId` in the `server.process` response.

Comment: That will nicely do it. Thanks @Rik

Comment: @Rik can you reply this as an answer, so I can approve? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server should return the `serverId` in the `server.process` response.